# How to remove the duplicate code in the different activities?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have some task from my study. I must start activity explicitly according to chosen a radio button. For example, we have two activity for choice and main activity. We select a radio button and run activity. But this minor activities are the same. The task does not say how to deal with the same activity. I'm wondering how to avoid this kind of code duplication. Without changing the task.

```
public class DisplayOneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_one);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_TEXT));
    textView.setTextColor(getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_COLOR, Color.RED));

    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(KEY_RANDOM_ALIGN, false)){
        Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        textView.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN[rnd.nextInt(TEXT_ALIGN.length)]);
    }

}
}

public class DisplayTwoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_one);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_TEXT));
    textView.setTextColor(getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_COLOR, Color.RED));

    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(KEY_RANDOM_ALIGN, false)){
        Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        textView.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN[rnd.nextInt(TEXT_ALIGN.length)]);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Refer to your respective IDE for tools like that under refactoring or something in those lines; For Intellij - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyzing-duplicates.html

Comment: You can implement an abstract BaseActivity and extend others from this. Example:  https://github.com/intermine/intermine-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/org/intermine/app/activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted one of the classes. Added `switch-case` that choose `layout.xml` according radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You can create BaseActivity with same code end extend DisplayOneActivity and DisplayTwoActivity with BaseActivity.

```
public class BaseDisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_one);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_TEXT));
    textView.setTextColor(getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_COLOR, Color.RED));

    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(KEY_RANDOM_ALIGN, false)){
        Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        textView.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN[rnd.nextInt(TEXT_ALIGN.length)]);
    }
}
```

And then just extend two other activities.

```
public class DisplayOneActivity extends BaseDisplayActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
}


public class DisplayTwoActivity extends BaseDisplayActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a baseActivity calss and extend your activites from this base activity.

for example you have created this base class:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity { }
```

and your class:

```
public class DisplayOneActivity extends BaseActivity {}
public class DisplayTwoActivity extends BaseActivity {}
```

now you can put common codes and methods in base activity and use in all child activity.